# Efficient way of redistributing (random.shuffle)

Tags: python, numpy

So, I currently have code looking like:

```
def shuffling(X,t):
    n = 100
    permute = list(range(n * 2))
    random.shuffle(permute)
    X = X[:, permute]
    t = t[permute]
    return X,t
```

X = 3 x 200 and t = 200 x 1, what I want to do is to shuffle these two matrices, so that each column ends up being with their corresponding target value in t. I wanted to do this with random.shuffle, but obviously I cant specify an axis for the elements, and I think it looks ugly to use numpy transpose twice, cause I need X to be 3x200 in the end of the day. Does anyone have any suggestions of how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`np.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) to generate a shuffled index for both arrays:

```
import numpy as np

def shuffling(X,t):
    r = np.random.permutation(len(t))
    X = X[:, r]
    t = t[r]
    return X, t
```

Comment: thank you for the response, the solution looks more elegant than the one I currently have!